# Why is the pow function returning NAN?

Tags: php, math

When using the following function, I sometimes get `NAN` returned for some inputs; I think I'm getting `NAN` when I'm using negative values for the variables. How can I fix this?

```
pow(($LY/$FY),(1/10)) - 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a check beforehand to ensure that `$LY/$FY` is positive. Alternatively, depending on what you're using it for, use the `abs()` function on that fraction to change negative numbers to positive ones.

Comment: If both arguments are non-negative integers and the result can be represented as an integer, the result will be returned with integer type, otherwise it will be returned as a float. [**`(pow)`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pow.php). So why would it return `NaN`?

Comment: "Elevating" a number to the power of 1/10 is the same as taking the 10th root of that number. Since any number to the power 10 is a positive number, the 10th root of a negative number does not exist.

Comment: Ahh.. :D an `imaginary number` ;)